# What is best practice for accessing two dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm a relatively new programmer and I was just wondering the best practice for accessing a certain row and column. From what I know both below work.

```
    array[r,c]
    array[r][c]
```

However, I've read that `array[r,c]` is better practice in general. Could someone tell me if I am correct and if so why as well as how it applies to higher-dimension arrays? Thank you so much for helping out a newcomer!

Comment: Those only work the same when `r` and `c` are scalar values, e.g. `arr[1][2]`.  But `arr[r,c]` allow you to use integer arrays, or mix in slices.  The `arr[r,c,d,:]` notation extends to higher dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you so much for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: `array[r,c]` is faster than `array[r][c]`**

Let compare the performance of two methods. I prepared a 2D array as follow:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
```

Then I compared the speed of two methods:

```py
%timeit array[42, 42]
```

The output is:

```
221 ns ± 7.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

and for the other method:

```py
%timeit array[42][42]
```

Output:

```
436 ns ± 8.28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

It is obvious array[r,c] is faster than `array[r][c]`. I think that is because in the `array[r][c]` approach, first `array[r]` will be calculated and returned. For the sake of argument, call this result `row=array[r]`. Then once again, `row[c]` will be calculated and returned.